# How do I show unanswered questions about topics I enjoy?

Tags: support

How do I show unanswered questions about topics I enjoy while excluding topics I dislike on [the Home Improvement and Do-it-Yourself Stack Exchange](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Your can edit the words in the following example to make it work for you:

```
answers:0 [electrical] -epoxy -shellac -enamel
```

If you copy and paste that text into the search bar, the the search engine will show questions:

> - with zero answers
> - which were filed under the `[electrical]` category.
> - the question does not contain the words "epoxy", "shellac", or "enamel"

Put a minus sign to the left of things which you do not want to see questions about.

Put nothing (or a space) to the left of things which you do want to see questions about.

To search for questions filed under a particular category, put the name of that category inside of square brackets.

You can find a full list of categories by clicking [**here**](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular).

If the word you care about is not

Instead of "***categories***", they are usually called "***tags***", but in the context of a Question and Answer website the following two phrases have almost the same meaning:

- "tagging a question with the `electrical` tag"
- "filling a question under the category of `electrical`"

---

The following shows what to type if you know a lot about showers, but are tired of questions about shower doors or removing old caulking.

```
answers:0 [shower] -[door] -caulking
```

If one of the things you care about is not one of the official [tags](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular), then type the word without any square brackets `[]`.

If you know a lot about plumbing, but not a lot about electrical work, there is no need to vote to close questions about electrical work. Just search for questions about electrical work which exclude plumbing.

```
answers:0 -[electrical] [plumbing]
```